# One ViewModel two Views with MVVMLight in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, mvvm-light

The datacontext's are configured in App.xaml (with MVVMLight), but when is one ViewModel one View.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMUserControl}">
   <views:UCViewSnow />
</DataTemplate>
```

I need use the same ViewModel with multiples Views, i added DataContext in codebehind for each View (.xaml.cs) but not working.

```
DataContext = ViewModel.ViewModelLocator.GetStaticVMuserControl;
```

I need to add DataContext according to parameters from app.config. 
I use WPF with framework 4.5.1 with MVVM light from nuget in VS 2015

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMUserControl}"> 
    <views:UCViewDark /> 
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMUserControl}">
    <views:UCViewSnow/> 
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Have you been able to identify any particular indications that it's "not working"? Or do you just have a general sense of foreboding, or malaise?

Comment: yes, i can't add two viewmodels in App.xaml with datatemplate. From codebehind in *.xaml.cs not working

" <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMUserControl}">
                <views:UCViewDark />
            </DataTemplate>"

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMUserControl}">
                <views:UCViewSnow/>
            </DataTemplate>

Comment: Are you having trouble editing the file? Is caps lock on?

Comment: No, i want to write code between tags for style. (i don't know it)

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to use a style to set a viewmodel? If so, you're creating only one copy of the viewmodel in the style, so that's the only copy you get. Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: No, write code in these comments.

Comment: What you're trying to do makes no sense. You need to research what DataTemplates are for.

Comment: The reason is that binding any viewmodel with any View in app.xaml with datatemplate works fine.
if i want to binding Viewmodel in codebehind "DataContext = MyViewModel" or binding in xaml "DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" not work.
I use MVVMLight and MahApps.Metro.

Comment: Show me enough code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see couple potential reasons why DataTemplate can didn't work.

1st - probably you didn't bind Content property of your view with your DataContext (vm:VMUserControl).
2nd - you use custom template of content control without ContentPresenter.

For example:
App.xaml

```
...
  <Application.Resources>
      <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
  </Application.Resources>
...
```

In your View

**Update:**
In case if you define two datatemplate for one DataType (viewmodel)
you additional should implement and use own ContentTemplateSelector.

```
<View ...
     DataSource={Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=YourViewModel}>

    <View.Resource>
        <ResourceDictionar>
               <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMUserControl}" 
                             x:Key="darkDataTemplate"> 
                   <views:UCViewDark /> 
               </DataTemplate>

               <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMUserControl}" 
                             x:Key="snowDataTemplate">
                  <views:UCViewSnow/> 
               </DataTemplate>

              <local:CustomContentTemplateSelector x:Key="yourContentTemplateSelector"
                     FirstDataTemplate={StaticResource snowDataTemplate}
                     SecondDataTemplate={StaticResource darkDataTemplate} />
        </ResourceDictionar>
    </View.Resource>

            <ContentControl Content={Binding} 
                            ContentTemplateSelector={StaticResource yourContentTemplateSelector}/>
```

CustomContentTemplateSelector.cs

```
public class CustomContentTemplateSelector:DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate FirstDataTemplate {get; set;}
    public DataTemplate SecondDataTemplate {get; set;}

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container){
    // here you should impelement logic for choose data template 
    // if (condition) 
    //      return FirstDataTemplate
    // else
    //      return SecondDataTemplate
}
}
```

Comment: I have <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" /> ready, but <View> ?
i use one window and usercontrol form "child" views.

Comment: Yes... you should use Window or UserControl instead of View in example.I just show common approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the problem is that datacontext binding in UserControl not work, when i add datacontext in UserControl show this:
[link]https://ibb.co/co5sbQ

Comment: this is my UserControl View:
'<UserControl ...
             DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=GetSoft}">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Tittle}" FontSize="50" Foreground="Black"></Label>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>'

Comment: Is code of UCViewSnow? If yes - you don't need specify DataContext.

Comment: Any way to do this ?
i write de piece of code but added without styles.

Comment: Not clear which type you are using: Is it vm:VMUserControl  or Test.Factory.Views.ViewModel.VCSoft (as I see on your image). Can you clarify condition which impact on choose of View?

Comment: P.S. I've updated my answer (added yours DataTemplates)